# @react-google-maps/api Google maps Marker not showing react JS

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps-api

Anyone can help?
My map is being rendered and working perfectly but my marker is not working I have been fighting with this for 4 hours.

```
    import React from "react";
    import { GoogleMap, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api";

    function Map({ lati, longi }) {
      const position = {
        // lat: lati,
        // lng: longi,
        lat: 33.7295198,
        lng: 73.0371536,
      };

      const onLoad = (marker) => {
        console.log("marker: ", marker);
      };

      return (
        <>
          <GoogleMap
            zoom={18}
            center={{ lat: lati, lng: longi }}
            mapContainerClassName="map-container"
          >
            <Marker onLoad={onLoad} position={position} />
          </GoogleMap>
        </>
      );
    }

    export default Map;
```

Comment: Instead of Marker use import MarkerF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
import { GoogleMap, MarkerF } from "@react-google-maps/api";


<MarkerF />
```

Comment: i came to know on local host we have to use MarkerF,
and for online hosting use Marker..
this conflict is because of a react update.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it might be because the strict mode renders the app twice, so the marker that we created at the first render is not re-created at the next render.

So, just disable the **strict mode** by removing the **React.StrictMode** from your **root.render** by changing this:

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

into this:

```
root.render(<App />);
```

Then you can render the maps in your app by making sure the **google.maps** object has been loaded before rendering the map:

App.js

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useJsApiLoader } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import Map from "./Map";

function App() {
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: "google-map-script",
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isLoaded);
  }, [isLoaded]);

  return <div>{isLoaded && <Map lati={-6.2297465} longi={106.829518} />}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Map.js

```
import React from "react";
import { GoogleMap, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api";

function Map({ lati, longi }) {
  const position = {
    lat: -6.175878,
    lng: 106.827196,
  };

  const onLoad = (marker) => {
    console.log("marker: ", marker);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <GoogleMap
        zoom={12}
        center={{ lat: lati, lng: longi }}
        mapContainerStyle={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }}
      >
        <Marker onLoad={onLoad} position={position} />
      </GoogleMap>
    </>
  );
}

export default Map;
```